# How can I remove an element from an array. Splice() isnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I declare a an array like this:

```
var myArray= [];
```

I then add Number elements

```
myArray.push(myNumber);
```

so array looks looks like this when I call myArray.toString();

> 1,4,3,9

I am trying to remove certain elements like this

```
for(var i = myArray.length; i >= 0; i--) {
   if(myArray[i] === theNumberIwantToRemove) {  //theNumberIwantToRemove ==4
      myArray.splice(i, 1);
   }
}
```

but it doesnt work. output still the same

> 1,4,3,9

Anyone know why or how to do it properly?

Comment: It should work perfectly well.

Comment: looks fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/KwEfw/

Comment: Are you trying to remove all elements that are "4", or are you trying to remove only the first or last occurence of said value?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a unique array and want to remove the only occurrence of a value then there is no need for jquery or a loop, just used good old javascript's [Array.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and [Array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

```
var array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    theNumberIwantToRemove = 5,
    position = array.indexOf(theNumberIwantToRemove);

if (position !== -1) {
    array.splice(position, 1);
}

alert(array);
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/KBgDe/)

If your array is not unique and you want to remove every occurrence of a value, then there is still no need for jquery and you can use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
var array = [0, 1, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 5, 8, 9],
    theNumberIwantToRemove = 5,
    position = array.indexOf(theNumberIwantToRemove),
    result = array.filter(function (element) {
        return element !== theNumberIwantToRemove;
    });

alert(result);
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/epU8g/)

If you desperately can not live without using jquery for every problem:
using [jQuery.inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)

```
var array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    theNumberIwantToRemove = 5
    position = $.inArray(theNumberIwantToRemove, array);

if (position !== -1) {
    array.splice(position, 1);
}

alert(array);
```

Using [jQuery.filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
var array = [0, 1, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 5, 8, 9],
    theNumberIwantToRemove = 5,
    position = array.indexOf(theNumberIwantToRemove),
    result = $(array).filter(function (index, element) {
        return element !== theNumberIwantToRemove;
    }).toArray();

alert(result);
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/qwbER/)

And there is also [jQuery.grep](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/)

```
var array = [0, 1, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 5, 8, 9],
    theNumberIwantToRemove = 5,
    position = array.indexOf(theNumberIwantToRemove),
    result = $.grep(array, function (element) {
        return element !== theNumberIwantToRemove;
    });

alert(result);
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/qwbER/)

Otherwise there doesn't appear to be anything wrong with your code.

Answer (score 3):

There is absolutely nothing wrong with your example.

This works fine, and gives the output: [1, 3, 9]. Test for yourself here: [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jfD6y/1/)

```
var myArray= [];

myArray.push(1,4,3,9);

console.log(myArray);

for(var i = myArray.length; i >= 0; i--) {
   if(myArray[i] === 4) {  //theNumberIwantToRemove ==4
      myArray.splice(i, 1);
   }
}

console.log(myArray);
```

**You will see this in your console:**

- [1, 4, 3, 9]
- [1, 3, 9]

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
var removeItem = 3;

obj = jQuery.grep(obj, function(value) {
    return value != removeItem;
});
```

Result:

```
[1, 2, 4, 5]
```

http://snipplr.com/view/14381/remove-item-from-array-with-jquery/